# Use database in child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, child-process

I try to execute in another process some database operations, so I used child_process for that.
But I cannot update my database from this process: there is no connection.

**app.js**

```
...
mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost/myDb);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function () {
  throw new Error('unable to connect to database');
});

// When the connection is disconnected
db.on('disconnected', function () {
  console.log('disconnected');
});

child_express.exec('node ' + __dirname + '/path/to/my/my-service.js', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if(err) console.error(stderr);
  else console.log(stdout);
});
```

**my-service.js**

```
MyModel = require('../models/my-model');
...
myModel.updateBook(book);
```

**my-model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState); => 0

var bookSchema = new Schema({..});  
var Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);

exports.updateBook = function(book) {
    Book.find({ bookId: book.bookId }, function (err, book) {
        console.log(book);
    });
};
```

How can I get the connection from child_process?

Comment: Why would you need to create a child_process for an async function? This doesn't leverage Node.js and its asynchronous processing model.

Comment: there are others sync code in 'my-service'

Comment: Your child process needs to set up its own connection, you can't share the one from the parent process.